# xml to json using php, failure to include xml <string>

Tags: php, json, xml

First, I am a total newbie when it comes to php. I am working on a website for an animal shelter (I'm a veterinarian/coder) and we are getting data from an online database of animals available for adoption. That xml file has an output like this (this is just a small part of the xml file):

```
<TotalWeight>64.5 lbs </TotalWeight>
<UnitWeight>lbs</UnitWeight>
<AdditionalPhotoUrls>
<string>https://eastbayspcapets.shelterbuddy.com//photos/lostfound/doc_55806.jpg</string>
  <string>https://eastbayspcapets.shelterbuddy.com//photos/lostfound/doc_55807.jpg</string>
  <string>https://eastbayspcapets.shelterbuddy.com//photos/lostfound/doc_55809.jpg</string>
  <string>https://eastbayspcapets.shelterbuddy.com//photos/lostfound/doc_55810.jpg</string>
  <string>https://eastbayspcapets.shelterbuddy.com//photos/lostfound/doc_55876.jpg</string>
  <string>https://eastbayspcapets.shelterbuddy.com//photos/lostfound/doc_55877.jpg</string>
  <string>https://eastbayspcapets.shelterbuddy.com//photos/lostfound/doc_71558.jpg</string>
  <string>https://eastbayspcapets.shelterbuddy.com//photos/lostfound/doc_71559.jpg</string>
</AdditionalPhotoUrls>
<AdoptionAmount>0.0000</AdoptionAmount>
```

The php file has this code that is converted to json:

```
 $item['totalweight'] = (string)$animal->TotalWeight;
$item['weight'] = (string)$animal->UnitWeight;
$item['photosX'] = (string)$animal->AdditionalPhotoUrls;
```

the json output to a file, using

```
echo file_put_contents('page.json', json_encode($data));
```

is successful for TotalWeight and UnitWeight but not for AdditionalPhotoUrls, with its strings. 
The son output is like this (again, small part of it):

```
{
"weight": "lbs",
"totalweight": "65",
"photosX": "\n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n    "
 },
```

I am unclear on how I should format:
    `(string)$animal->AdditionalPhotoUrls;` to not get strings rather then end up with \n

to get all the multiple `<string>`. Currently the json file is empty for `photosX`.

Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

this xml doesn't contain any attributes, so we can easily type:

`<?php
$xml = '<root>
<TotalWeight>64.5 lbs </TotalWeight>
<UnitWeight>lbs</UnitWeight>
<AdditionalPhotoUrls>
<string>https://eastbayspcapets.shelterbuddy.com//photos/lostfound/doc_55806.jpg</string>
  <string>https://eastbayspcapets.shelterbuddy.com//photos/lostfound/doc_55807.jpg</string>
  <string>https://eastbayspcapets.shelterbuddy.com//photos/lostfound/doc_55809.jpg</string>
  <string>https://eastbayspcapets.shelterbuddy.com//photos/lostfound/doc_55810.jpg</string>
  <string>https://eastbayspcapets.shelterbuddy.com//photos/lostfound/doc_55876.jpg</string>
  <string>https://eastbayspcapets.shelterbuddy.com//photos/lostfound/doc_55877.jpg</string>
  <string>https://eastbayspcapets.shelterbuddy.com//photos/lostfound/doc_71558.jpg</string>
  <string>https://eastbayspcapets.shelterbuddy.com//photos/lostfound/doc_71559.jpg</string>
</AdditionalPhotoUrls>
<AdoptionAmount>0.0000</AdoptionAmount>
</root>';
$json = json_encode(simplexml_load_string($xml));
echo $json;`

Comment: Updated my question.